# How do I use Artisan command in code Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I use Artisan command line in my php caode Ex: `php artisan --version` to `<?php echo 'version show here'; ?>`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Answer (score 35):

You can call Artisan command from your controller as below :

```
//calling of migrate install 
     Artisan::call('migrate:install');
```

i.e. just use

```
Artisan::call('Commandname');
```

For more info check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan)

Comment: Dont forget to add
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;`

Comment: @MischaFirges You don't need that, just use the root facade. `\Artisan::call()`