# Could not open input file artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm using process to run command in my code

```
$commandRaw = 'php artisan mytest:testCommand p1 p2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &';
$commands = explode(' ', $commandRaw);
$process = new Process($commands);
$process->run();
return $process->getOutput();
```

But when running, I was received error message

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

My artisan path is D:/src/parent/laravel_api/artisan, so I tried to replace artisan in command by this path, but It didn't work

However, when I using cmd to run `php D:/src/parent/laravel_api/artisan mytest:testCommand p1 p2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`, It worked

How can I define artisan path in code?

Comment: You can run artisan commands from your code easier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313052/how-do-i-use-artisan-command-in-code-laravel

Comment: @GertB. How can I pass an array as parameter for command?

Comment: you can find that here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193314/could-not-open-input-file-artisan

Answer (score 3):

Could not open input file: artisan this error occur when you opened the cmd in parent directory you have to open the cmd where your actual project files are.This thing work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).